# error when deploying jersey/helloworld-osgi-webapp on glassfish 3.1.2.2

Tags: java, jersey, osgi, glassfish-3, apache-felix

When trying to deploy the sample jersey war bundle code (helloworld-osgi-webapp on git: https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/tree/master/jersey/samples/helloworld-osgi-webapp) on Glassfish 3.1.2.2, I am getting the following osgi error:

```
remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app: 
  org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle war-bundle [344]:
  Unable to resolve 344.0: missing requirement [344.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.jersey.api.core)(version>=1.18.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))).
  Please see server.log for more details.
  Command deploy failed
```

Why maven felix plugin is not embedding the libraries in the war ? 
Thanx in advance,
M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct reason is that in your application it's not configured to do that, and the reason it's not is that in OSGi world it shouldn't.

From [pom](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/blob/master/jersey/samples/helloworld-osgi-webapp/war-bundle/pom.xml) that it is in provided scope:

```
<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
<version>${project.version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
<classifier>cobertura</classifier>
```

And it will only embed runtime & compiled scopes:

```
<Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
```

and uses OSGi standard import-package to import jersey-servlet dependencies as OSGi services:

```
<Import-Package>com.sun.jersey.api.core,com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet,*</Import-Package>
```

In the OSGi world, dependencies should be deployed as separate OSGi bundles, and not embedded in wars. That's what your example is doing. So, you should deploy jersey as a separate OSGi bundle.

Comment: (if you really, really want to embed that, you should change the dependency scope from 'provided' to 'compile' and remove relevant import-package)

Comment: My problem is that I need to deploy my OSGi wab on a Glassfish 3.1.2.2 which  has jersey 1.11, and I wanted to use a 2.x version of jersey. My workaround for now, is to use 1.11. Should I upgrade jersey on my GF? Or is it a better practive to embed my jersey dependencies ?

Comment: @mehdi-terraneen it's better practice to upgrade it on glassfish, but note that you'd need a valid, osgified version.