# Error when deploying osgi-http-service on Glassfish

Tags: maven, glassfish, osgi, jersey-2.0

I try to deploy a sample Jersey code (osgi-http-service) to my local glassfish server. But I got this version complaints. I've used the solution mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939901/error-when-deploying-jersey-helloworld-osgi-webapp-on-glassfish-3-1-2-2), but it did not work out.

I download the Jersey code and only build a sub-project which is osgi-http-service in example. (from https://github.com/jersey/jersey)
I used Maven to build it and it was successful.

When I tried to deploy it on my local glassfish server, it shows an error in the prompt, as below:

```
> asadmin deploy --type=osgi hello1-1.0.0.jar

remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : org.osgi.framework.BundleException: 
Unresolved constraint in bundle hello1 [349]: Unable to resolve 349.0: missing requirement [349.0] osgi.wiring.package;
(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.jersey.servlet)(version>=2.22.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))). 
Please see server.log for more details. Command deploy failed.
```

I am sure that the glassfish server is up and running.

I find out that the highest version of jersey-container-servlet is 2.22 or 2.23, based on this [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet).
I tried both 2.22 and 2.23 in my POM file, but none of them works.

**I just wonder, is there anything wrong with the version here?**
could you give me some hints what should be the right version of the dependencies?

My POM file **dependency section** is shown below.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.22</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
       <version>2.22</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.22</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My POM file **build plugin** section is shown below.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Export-Package>org.glassfish.jersey.examples.osgihttpservice</Export-Package>
                    <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                    <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
                    <Bundle-Activator>org.glassfish.jersey.examples.osgihttpservice.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>hello1</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Implementation-Title>jersey-osgi-http-service-bundle</Implementation-Title>
                    <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                </instructions>
                <unpackBundle>true</unpackBundle>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The glassfish log is also attached, for your reference. The glassfish log is essentially the same as the error message in the prompt.

```
[2016-06-17T21:55:07.982-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [][javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=43 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1466225707982] [levelValue: 1000] [[Exception while loading the app : 
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle hello1 [377]: Unable to resolve 377.0: missing requirement [377.0] osgi.wiring.package;
 (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.jersey.servlet)(version>=2.22.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
 org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle hello1 [377]: 
Unable to resolve 377.0: missing requirement [377.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.glassfish.jersey.servlet)(version>=2.22.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3974)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2037)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)
        at org.glassfish.extras.osgicontainer.OSGiDeployedBundle.startBundle(OSGiDeployedBundle.java:107)
        at org.glassfish.extras.osgicontainer.OSGiDeployedBundle.resume(OSGiDeployedBundle.java:83)
        at org.glassfish.extras.osgicontainer.OSGiDeployedBundle.start(OSGiDeployedBundle.java:67)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.executeCommand(CommandResource.java:404)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.execCommandSimpInMultOut(CommandResource.java:234)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor229.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:309)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:375)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.JerseyContainerCommandService$3.service(JerseyContainerCommandService.java:173)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)]]
```

Just FYI.

I also downloaded the following jars and installed in my glassfish server:

```
- jersey-client.jar
- jersey-common.jar
- jersey-container-servlet.jar
- jersey-container-servlet-core.jar
- jersey-media-jaxb.jar
- jersey-server.jar
```

I met the same error as I deployed the Jersey sample code. For example,

```
> asadmin deploy --force --type=osgi jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.jar

remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : org.osgi.framework.BundleException:
Unresolved constraint in bundle org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core [401]: Unable to resolve 401.0: 
missing requirement [401.0] osgi.wiring.package; 
(&(osgi.wiring.package=jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base)(version>=2.22.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))).
Please see server.log for more details.
Command deploy failed.
```

Thank you very much for your insights and comments.